# Can't match regex for django url (methods described earlier on stackowerflow don't work)

Tags: python, django, url

Can't match regex for django url
you need to process an incoming request from the frontend

```
 "GET /api/city_list/9/?q=test HTTP/1.0" 404 Not Found

 "GET /api/city_list/9/?q=tt HTTP/1.0" 404 Not Found
```

I tried several options

```
path('api/city_list/<int:id>/?q=<str:q>', api_city_list, name='api_city_list'),
```

does not work

```
re_path(r'^api/city_list/\d+/\?|&q=\w', api_city_list, name='api_city_list'),
```

does not work

```
re_path(r'^api/city_list/<int:id>/(?P<q>\D+)', api_city_list, name='api_city_list'),
```

does not work

views.py does not reach the debugger.

url checker fails

Friends, tell me how to do it, otherwise I'm already confused with regular expressions for Django

(Django 3.1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to add the query string matching in your url paths, so you can change the url to just:

```
path('api/city_list/<int:id>/', api_city_list, name='api_city_list'),
```

Then in your view, if you want to access the query parameters, you can use `request.GET`.

```
def api_city_list(request, id):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    ...
```

All query params in this url will automatically be passed to `request.GET`, so no need to match those in your url config.

Comment: What doesn't work? The url config I shared was not part of the things you tried in your question.